# Swift "Reference to property ... closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit"

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm coming from Python and JavaScript background, and I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting this error and how to fix it. "Reference to property 'eggMessage' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit". I'm just trying to update the text of the eggMessage label with the current countdown. (Swift5, xcode 13)

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var eggMessage: UILabel!
    
    var softTime = 5
    var mediumTime = 7
    var hardTime = 12
    
    func updateMessage(text: String) {
        eggMessage.text = text
    }
    
    func createTimer(timeLeft: Int) {
       var countdown = timeLeft
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) {
            [weak self] timer in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                if countdown > 0 {
                    
                    
                    print(countdown, "<--- TIME LEFT")
                    eggMessage.text = String(countdown) // <---- ERROR!!
                    updateMessage(text: String(countdown)) // <---- ERROR!!
                    countdown -= 1
                } else {
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), execute: {
            timer.fire()
        }) 
    }

    @IBAction func eggSelection(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let hardness: String = sender.currentTitle!
        
        switch hardness {
        case "Soft":
            print(softTime)
            createTimer(timeLeft: softTime)
        case "Medium":
            print(mediumTime)
        case "Hard":
            print(hardTime)
        default:
            print("pass")
        }
  
    }
}
```

Comment: `[weak self]` means `self` _might_ be available (not nil) so you need to treat it as an optional and use `self?.eggMessage.text = ...` which means "if self is available then update eggMessage with a new value otherwise do nothing"

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that your closure's lifetime is not tied to the lifetime of your ViewController. You need to tell the compiler the relationship you desire for the two lifetimes. In general, use `[weak self]` and `self?.foo`; this tells the compiler that you want the ViewController to be able to destruct at will (like when the app terminates), and you want the closure not to crash your app if it runs after the ViewController has destructed.

To get a solid grasp of the issue, read about retain cycles in the [Swift Book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).